# My system login works fine if password is plain text, but not when password is hashed

Tags: php, mysql

**Login code**

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once 'database.php';


    if(isset($_GET['cerrar_sesion'])){
        session_unset();

        session_destroy();
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['rol'])){
        switch($_SESSION['rol']){
            case 1:
                header('location: admin.php');
            break;



            default:
        }
    }

    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password1'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
       $password1 =$_POST ['password1'];


        $db = new Database();

        $query = $db->connect()->prepare('SELECT*FROM usuarios WHERE username = :username AND password = :password1');

        $query->execute(['username' => $username, 'password1' => $password1]);

        $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

        if($row == true){
            // validar rol
            $rol = $row[3];
            $_SESSION['rol'] = $rol;
            $_SESSION['Codigo'] = $_POST['Codigo'];;


            switch($_SESSION['rol']){
                case 1:
                    header('location: admin.php');
                break;


                default:
            }
        }else{
            // no existe el usuario
        }
    }
```

Database query

```
<?php

class Database{

    private $host;
    private $db;
    private $user;
    private $password;
    private $charset;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->host = '192.168.1.45';
        $this->db = 'fil';
        $this->user = 'root';
        $this->password = 'five';
        $this->charset = 'utf8mb4';
    }

    function connect(){
        try{
            $connection = "mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db . ";charset=" . $this->charset;
            $options = [
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
            ];

            $pdo = new PDO($connection, $this->user, $this->password, $options);

            return $pdo;
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            print_r('Error connection: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Insert code hashing password with MD5

```
include ("database.php");
$password1 = $_POST["password1"]; 
    if( 
      isset($_POST["Nombre"])&&
      isset($_POST["apellido"])&&
       isset($_POST["username"])&&
       isset($_POST["password1"])&&
       isset($_POST["Es_de_etc"])&&
      isset($_POST["Nivel_imparte"])&&
      isset($_POST["rol_id"])
         ) {
          $password1 = md5($password1); 
          $conn-> query ("INSERT INTO
               usuarios(
               Nombre,
               apellido,
               username,
               password,
               Es_de_etc,
               Nivel_imparte,
               rol_id
              ) 
              VALUES (
              '".$_POST["Nombre"]."',
              '".$_POST["apellido"]."',
              '".$_POST["username"]."',
               '".$password1."',
              '".$_POST["Es_de_etc"]."',
              '".$_POST["Nivel_imparte"]."',
              '".$_POST["rol_id"]."'

              )
              ");
          header("location: registro.php");
    }
```

Comment: Please translate your post to English.

Comment: En el codigo de Login, intenta cambiar `$query->execute(['username' => $username, 'password1' => $password1]);` con `$query->execute(['username' => $username, 'password1' => md5($password1)]);`

Comment: I sympathize with you, but this site is [English only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676/364543). The point is that this site is supposed to have value for you *and* for everyone who follows. Instead of everyone translating to English, you need to translate once.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not in English

Comment: @MarcoLeiva: necesitas escribir las preguntas en ingles, o te pueden borrar el post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the OP is saying that his login function works when the password is in clear, but fails when the password is encrypted.

From what we can see, it looks like with encryption (or better said, hashing), the password for a new user gets stored in the database hashed with `md5`. However, the login script still compares the plain text input password.

Very simply, the comparison should be between the value in the database, and the `md5` hash of the input login password.

As such, changing:

```
$query->execute(['username' => $username, 'password1' => $password1]);
```

to:

```
$query->execute(['username' => $username, 'password1' => md5($password1]));
```

should solve the problem.

Comment: I thank you very much you have helped me, it worked wonderfully
thanks for your time friend